# Should I annotate additional information besides the categories I already need in a text?

Tags: neural-network, lstm, rnn, transformer, annotation

I have a dataset with bank transfer reasons. They vary a lot because humans wrote them.
From the reasons that are linked to invoice payments I need to extract several things:

- *invoice number(s)*
- *IBAN*
- *counterparty*

Before I use any NN algorithm I need to annotate the data.

So, for example, I have these rows:

1. "Bank transfer for INV. **00234**, **00435**/*2022.01.13* [BIC] **[IBAN]** **Company Ltd**"
2. "Payment of invoice **00034**-*1120,34* on *02.17* [BIC] **[IBAN]** **Company 2 inc**."

In case 1, I have:

- invoice numbers: 00234, 00435
- IBAN - [IBAN]
- counterparty - Company Ltd

In case 2, I have:

- invoice number: 00034
- IBAN - [IBAN]
- counterparty - Company 2 inc

I have also annotated invoice prefixes such as inv, INV, invoice, etc.

My question is, should I add additional annotations such as "date" (2022.01.13, 02.17) or "sum paid" (1120,34)? Could they be helpful for a transformer, for example, to find out what an invoice is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might depend on the algorithm you choose and on how various your data is.

Solution 1:
If every potential case is precisely identified, it could be better to classify every field precisely.

Solution 2:
However, if there are a lot of potential cases, including unexpected ones (ex: notes or chaotic order), a good solution could be to define an annotation "other" to group any other field that doesn't match the others.

Solution 3:
A mix of solutions to reduce errors as much as possible in every field:

- Use filters to recognize fields like IBAN or invoice numbers
- Use NN trained on company names to recognize companies

I'm afraid that 100% NN would lose efficiency in recognizing very different fields that include numeric and text data.

Comment: Well, the format of the dates varies. Since it is written by humans and there is no strict requirement for the format you can see dates written as dd-mm-yyyy, dd-mm, yyyymmdd, etc. Moreover, I am afraid my algorithm will not distinguish between date and invoice number, especially when the date has no separators. I plan to use RNN or a Transformer, which takes into account the 'context' (like the word invoice in front of a list of numbers) but I am not positive it will work.

Comment: Understood: I've added a  3rd solution, maybe it could work even better :)